# Prevent back button after logout in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular

So there's a login page and let's say a dashboard with certain data fields. When I press logout from the dashboard it redirects me to the login page. But when I hit back button, it brings me back tot he dashboard and technically let's me access data I shouldn't be able to access.
It was solved by refreshing after pressing back button, because it seems that is the page cache loading from memory which needs to be refreshed. But I don't want the user to have to manually refresh. 
Any workaround to that, or a completely different solution would be great.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2 or higher?

Comment: I am using AngularJS, and Piyush's answer helped achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular, you can use @hostListner(angular decorator). that is used for handling dom events in angular.
in your project, you can help localStorage and @hostListner

store client information on local storage with javascript.
[store local storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GViwN.png)

and then in the log-in page
add @hostListner event in component.ts file
[event handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p328Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Implement session validation in each of your route $routeChangeStart event. Whenever user loggout clear the session data and redirect it default route which should be your login page.